# Cannot validate AAD access token - IDX10511: Signature validation failed

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, access-token

I am trying to build a method which validates my tokens. I am retrieving my tokens from Azure Active Directory with Open Id Connect Authorization Code Flow. The tokens that I get are the **access_token** and the **id_token**. I am using .NET Core.

My validation code is as follows:

```cs
string stsDiscoveryEndpoint = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration";
var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration> configManager = new ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration>(stsDiscoveryEndpoint, new OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever());
OpenIdConnectConfiguration config = configManager.GetConfigurationAsync().Result;

try
{
  TokenValidationParameters validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
  {
     ValidIssuers = new [] { "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantid/v2.0" },
     ValidAudiences = new [] { "client-Id" },
     ValidateAudience = true,
     ValidateIssuer = true,
     IssuerSigningKeys = config.SigningKeys,
     ValidateLifetime = true
  };
  var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
  SecurityToken validatedToken = null;
  tokenHandler.ValidateToken(token.AccessToken, validationParameters, out validatedToken);
  return validatedToken != null;
 }
 catch (SecurityTokenInvalidSignatureException ex)
 {
   return false;
 }
 catch(SecurityTokenValidationException)
 {
   return false;
 }
```

The code below **works** for the **id_token** BUT
**does not work** for the **access_token**

The error message which I am getting when this method is executed for the access_token is:

**IDX10511: Signature validation failed. Keys tried: 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509SecurityKey , KeyId: CtAAALb-8NsDe333734859crfOc
'. 
kid: 'CtAAALb-8NsDe333734859crfOc'. 
Exceptions caught:
 ' '**

Answer (score 7):

the nonce header has to be SHA2 hashed before signature verification

Here is an example of code where you can see

```
jsonToken.Header.Add("nonce", hashedNonce);
```

```
        private static bool _hashNonceBeforeValidateToken = true;
        private const string MicrosoftGraphApplicationId = "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000";
        private const string MicrosoftIssuer = "https://sts.windows.net";


    public static bool ValidateTokenSignature(string accessToken, ApplicationConfiguration applicationConfiguration) {
        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var jsonToken = tokenHandler.ReadJwtToken(accessToken);
        string[] parts = accessToken.Split('.');
        string header = parts[0];
        string payload = parts[1];
        string signature = parts[2];

        //hash nonce and update header with the hash before validating
        if (_hashNonceBeforeValidateToken &&
            jsonToken.Header.TryGetValue("nonce", out object nonceAsObject))
        {
            string plainNonce = nonceAsObject.ToString();
            using (SHA256 sha256 = SHA256.Create())
            {
                byte[] hashedNonceAsBytes = sha256.ComputeHash(
                    System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainNonce));
                string hashedNonce = Base64Url.Encode(hashedNonceAsBytes);
                jsonToken.Header.Remove("nonce");
                jsonToken.Header.Add("nonce", hashedNonce);
                header = tokenHandler.WriteToken(jsonToken).Split('.')[0];

                accessToken = $"{header}.{payload}.{signature}";
            }
        }

        //get the Microsoft JWT signature public key 
        string stsDiscoveryEndpoint = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{applicationConfiguration.TenantId}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration";
        if (jsonToken.Header.TryGetValue("ver", out object version) && version.ToString() == "1.0")
        {
            stsDiscoveryEndpoint = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{applicationConfiguration.TenantId}/.well-known/openid-configuration";
        }
        var openidConfigManaged = new ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration>(stsDiscoveryEndpoint,
            new OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever(),
            new HttpDocumentRetriever());
        var configTask = openidConfigManaged.GetConfigurationAsync();
        configTask.Wait();
        var config = configTask.Result;

        var parameteres = new TokenValidationParameters()
        {
            RequireAudience = true,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidAudiences = new[] { applicationConfiguration.ApplicationId, MicrosoftGraphApplicationId },

            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidIssuers = new string[] { $"{MicrosoftIssuer}/{applicationConfiguration.TenantId}/", config.Issuer },

            IssuerSigningKeys = config.SigningKeys,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,

            RequireExpirationTime = true,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
        };

        var claimPrincipal = tokenHandler.ValidateToken(
            accessToken, parameteres, out SecurityToken validatedToken);

        return claimPrincipal.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
    }
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how/where you figured this out? This seems like a lot of code I'd be responsible for maintaining, so I'd be curious what documentation or library source code this came from... or some authority (such as Microsoft) that explains why I'd need this.

Comment: Thank you so much. Was looking for an answer to this for so long. I succesfully replicated this code in Node.JS. I used jose for fetching the keys and token verification. I also had to use `base64url` buffer encoding instead of `base64`.

Comment: This works, I could not get access token validation to work without first hashing the nonce. I too am curious if there is official documentation on this...

Comment: Do not mess with nonce, just create your custom scope and MSAL will not add nonce to the JWT header.

Answer (score 1):

Is the `access_token` audience your API or Microsoft Graph/other 3rd party service? It only makes sense to validate the tokens that **you** (your service) consumes, other audiences will take care of this on their own. On top of that, the signature of that JWT may be opaque to you.

See this for more - https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/issues/812#issuecomment-456700813

Comment: The tokens are stored and used in my own service only. I want to validate these in the moment that I receive the tokens from AAD.

Comment: If you're using ADAL/MSAL, the issuer is validated by default, or you could do
`new TokenValidationParameters {    ValidAudience = clientId, ValidateIssuer = true }`. It's easy to test, capture a valid access_token and then use curl/Postman to call your API with the token's signature amended. Better yet, mock it in your tests.

Answer (score 1):

This happens when you do not create your custom scope. In this case MSAL generates JWT having "nonce" in the header. Such JWTs cannot be easily validated by your .net code. But if you DO create your custom scope (like here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/quickstart-configure-app-expose-web-apis) and specify it while requesting access token then MSAL will not add `nonce` into the header and such JWT can be validated without extra pain.